# Remove fields from objects before passing to json

Tags: c#, json, jira-rest-api

I have a Jira object that I use with the Jira rest api; when I only had one Jira project therefore one set of fields to deal with this was working fine, however now I have many different projects with different fields available, I need to be able to dynamically remove the fields that certain projects don't need before I pass it to Jira. I know I could have a custom object per project, but I would rather make and maintain a single object that has all the possible items, and remove what isn't need for each project before passing it off to the api.

Default fields:

```
[DataContract]
public class FieldsUpdate
{
    [DataMember(Name = "issuetype")]
    public Issuetype issuetype;
    [DataMember(Name = "project")]
    public Project project;
    [DataMember(Name = "labels")]
    public List<object> labels = new List<object>();
    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string description;
    [DataMember(Name = "summary")]
    public string summary;
    [DataMember(Name = "customfield_10400")]
    public object ExpectedDelDate;        
}
```

Upper fields level:

```
[DataContract]
public class JiraItmAddUpdate
{

    [DataMember(Name = "fields")]
    public FieldsUpdate fields = new FieldsUpdate();

    public JiraItmAddUpdate()
    {
        FieldsUpdate fields = new FieldsUpdate();
    }

}
```

Example of current use:

```
JiraItmAddUpdate JiriUpdateFlds = new JiraItmAddUpdate();
JiriUpdateFlds.fields.summary = "Some Summary";
JiriUpdateFlds.fields.description = "Some Description"
var Request = JiraHttpClient.Client.PutAsJsonAsync(str_IssueKey + "/", JiriUpdateFlds);
```

This would produce something like

```
    {"fields": {
                "summary": "Some Summary",
                "description" = "Some Description"
                }
     }
```

As an example what sometimes I need to end up with is just summary, but it must retain the "fields" parent. I've looked at ExpandoObject but can't seem to get it to do what I want, anyone got any idea's how I can send up with a dynamic object without having to build a separate class of fields for each jira project?

Comment: The correct solution to this is to build up a class hierarchy, this will likely make it easier for you in code as well, as you no longer have to guess which fields need a value for post type X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the jira class the base class and inherite this for each project. You then only need to convert to the base class.

Comment: Any chance you can give me an example please?

Comment: The jira class which can be used by the jira api is now your baseclass. For each project you inherite the base class and add a function "ConvertToBaseClass()" to "convert" the object to the base class. So now you only need to call "ConvertToBaseClass()" on the ProjectJira object to get a used object. TLDR: Dont try to remove unnecessary properties, jut convert it to the needed object.

Comment: By making a function that converts the inherited class to the base class would I not just end up with all the fields I don't want again?

Comment: Why should the baseclass contains more fields after converting then before?

Comment: That's the thing, the object that gets passed to Jira needs to contain less fields, or the Jira Api will return an error as not all fields are available for each project. Sorry if I have misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: JiraBase Class for example contains: Name, ID,Password. Your ProjectJira class has Name,ID,Password,Settings. If you convert now ProjectJira to JiraBase Class then JiraBase only contains Name,ID,Password

Comment: Taking your example what I need is JiraBase contains: Name, ID,Password. ProjectJira contains Name,ID. So if I now convert ProjectJira to JiraBase wouldn't I end up with Name, ID,Password?

Comment: Oh I see sorry you are you suggesting that I should have only the fields that are relevant to all the projects, then add the additional fields in the Derived Class; sorry I needed more coffee to be fully awake, yes I see that could work.